# Why it compiles with different type?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, il2cpp

Error:

```
IL2CPP error for type 'Namespace.SubNamespace.MyClass/<MyIEnumeratorFunc>d__20' in assembly 'Path\MyUnityProject\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\VisualStudioSolutionName.dll'
Additional information: Interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<System.Object> method T System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<System.Object>::get_Current() not implemented on non-abstract class Namespace.SubNamespace.MyClass/<MyIEnumeratorFunc>d__20
```

Unity expect System.Collections.IEnumerator and I try to use IEnumerator:

1. I tried to write directly

   ```
   private System.Collections.IEnumerator MyIEnumeratorFunc(){}
   ```
2. I tried to remove

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generics;
   ```

   and append it to each List/Dictionary entry
   Everything works in Editor, but I get error I described above:
   Seems like it tries to use System.Collections.GENERICS.IEnumerator.

Also, the error disappears if I use source code (not .dll)

Also, you can reproduce it by creating .dll with any IEnumerator/async function (even empty) and build for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Project name.
Solution is

1. Right mouse click on Project name (not solution name) in Solution Explorer.
2. Properties
3. "Application" tab
4. Assembly name -> set to the same to .dll file name (without ".dll")